# Symbol or name for Basismatrix of Linear Programming

Tags: matrices, linear-programming, convention

This question is about the Basismatrix in the context of Linear Programming.

Basically (haha!) we have the Matrix of the standard (or normal) form, which consists of (**A**|**E**) with the coefficient matrix **A** and the identity matrix **E**.

How do you call this matrix? Maybe you could call it **H** but that could lead to confusion with the Hamiltonian and seems quite unusual. Or call it still **A** but with a remark that I have two *different* **A**'s in my document? Or is it possible to use another typeset? Could you recommend a better alternative?